# How to find the formula of a curved graph to find other points

Tags: curves

I am looking to find a formula to get other y points from x values. The points I know are:

```
1,50
50,50
5000,5
8000,2
10000,2
```

Basically the y axis doesn't get any higher than 50 and no lower than 2. How would I find the formula to get y with other x values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone comes across this, the way I figured it out was using Excel. I put in the X and Y numbers in columns and created a graph. From there, I played around with different trend lines to figure out the one that best fits. In my case it was a logarithmic scale. Excel gives you the option to show the formula and you can use that. Hope this helps others.